# Display Woocommerce tax as seperate table row

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using Woocommerce and want to display the tax ("incl. tax") in a seperate table row line above the totals(in cart and checkout), instead of right behind the totals in the same line like it is by default. I found this

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_order_item_totals', 'dks_tax_new_line');
function dks_tax_new_line($total_rows)
{
    //Define order total again without the (Includes %s) label
    $total_rows['order_total']['value'] = $this->get_formatted_order_total();

    //Make an array with tax
    $taxes = [];
    foreach ($this->get_tax_totals() as $code => $tax)
    {
        $taxes[] = sprintf('%s', $tax->formatted_amount);
    }

    //Add the tax row to the array that get_order_item_totals() outputs
    $total_rows['tax_line'] = [
        'label' => 'Herfra 25% Moms:',
        'value' => sprintf(implode(', ', $taxes)),
    ];

    return $total_rows;
}
```

But it doesn't work. Can anyone help?
Thanks!

Comment: What is `$total_rows` returning? And what would you like to have in it?

Comment: @Ronnie Oosting: I found this code online,I have not a lot of knowledge in PHP. I want the taxes which are usually displayed right after the totals in the same table row to be displayed in a SEPERATE table row above the totals. See this screenshot: https://q-linn.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/Screenshot_1.png

Comment: Well you are using `return`. I will write you an example, one moment ;-)

Comment: yo need to modify the cart & checkout Template to achieve your target the code you are using  for the order-received page that's why it's not working